# List files within a folder after a filename(pattern) - Linux

Tags: linux, unix

```
# ls -la /var/lib/my-app/my-app*

-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742635 May  4 21:01 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001211
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741971 May  5 20:07 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001212
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741874 May  6 21:01 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001213
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1134106954 May  8 06:50 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001214
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073743025 May  9 10:57 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001215
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742068 May 10 15:19 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001216
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741886 May 11 19:26 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001217
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742868 May 12 21:15 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001218
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742220 May 13 23:36 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001219
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742065 May 15 07:21 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001220
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742428 May 16 12:18 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001221
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741955 May 17 15:04 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001222
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742263 May 18 17:21 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001223
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742288 May 19 19:46 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001224
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741896 May 20 22:45 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001225
-rw-rw---- 2 root root 1073742131 May 22 10:37 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001226
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  967375006 May 23 13:37 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001227
```

Given this as my folder content, what I want is to list all files after the file 
*my-app.001219*

Output would look like:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742220 May 13 23:36 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001219
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742065 May 15 07:21 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001220
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742428 May 16 12:18 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001221
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741955 May 17 15:04 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001222
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742263 May 18 17:21 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001223
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073742288 May 19 19:46 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001224
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1073741896 May 20 22:45 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001225
-rw-rw---- 2 root root 1073742131 May 22 10:37 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001226
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  967375006 May 23 13:37 /var/lib/my-app/my-app.001227
```

NB: given filename will be ever increasing natural numbers.

Edit: Can I also include the file as well(index 001219 in this case)

Comment: You say that you want to include all files _after_ the given file name, but when comparing to the first listing, your output prints out all files _before_ the given file name. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: listing is just opposite, what I mean is filename with higher natural numbers will be listed. BTW editing the question thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to delete lines in the given range:

```
ls -lat /var/lib/new_folder/my-app* | sed '1,/my-app\.001219/d'
```

To print also the matching line, just invert the condition, i.e. tell sed to *print from the matching line to the end:

```
 sed -n '/my-app\.001219/,$p'
```

Comment: It worked, is there any way if I can also include the file?

Comment: appreciate your help.